# Python - Scrapy crawling myrecipes.com issue

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape recipe website: my recipes.com in order to extract recipe details that I will store in sqlite db in android application. I was able to extract all the recipe details except for the recipe duration time. The issue here is not all recipes share the same format; some contain cook time and prep time, some contain total time and some don't. Below is the code that i used to scrape the website plus the html code that I was targeting the duration.

I tried to run the code, but the output would not register.  I suspect the issue is in the if-else statement which i need in order to account for different recipe formats. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from myrecipes.items import MyrecipesRecipe, Ingredient, Nutrients

class MyrecipesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myrecipes" # name of the spider to be used when crawling
    allowed_domains = ["myrecipes.com"] # where the spider is allowed to go
    start_urls = ["http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/indian-chickpea-vegetable-stew"]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response) # the selector
    recipe = MyrecipesRecipe()

    # Name
    recipe['name'] = sel.xpath("substring-before(//title/text(),' Recipe')").extract()

    # Cuisine
    recipe['cuisine'] = "Indian"

    # Ingredients
    ingredients = []
    ingredient_nodes = sel.xpath('//*[@class = "panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-ingredients"]/div/div')

    for ingredient_node in ingredient_nodes:
        try:
            name = ingredient_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-ingredients"]/div/div/span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()').extract()
            quantity = ingredient_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-ingredients"]/div/div/span[@itemprop = "amount"]/text()').extract()
        except:
            continue

        ingredient = Ingredient()
        ingredient['name'] = name
        ingredient['quantity'] = quantity
        ingredients.append(ingredient)

    recipe['ingredients'] = ingredients

    # Directions
    instructions = []
    instruction_nodes = sel.xpath('//div[@itemprop = "instructions"]/div[@class = "field-instructions"]/div/div[@class = "field-item even"]')

    for instruction_node in instruction_nodes:
        try:
            instruction_step = instruction_node.xpath('//div[@itemprop = "instructions"]/div[@class = "field-instructions"]/div/div[@class = "field-item even"]/*/text()').extract()
        except:
            continue
        instructions.append(instruction_step)

    recipe['instructions'] = instructions

    # Nutritional Info
    nutrients = []
    nutrient_nodes = sel.xpath('//div[@class = "panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-nutrition-data"]/div/div[@itemprop = "nutrition"]')

    for nutrient_node in nutrient_nodes:
        try:
            name = nutrient_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-nutrition-data"]/div[contains (@class, "field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-recipe-nutrition")]/div/text()').extract()
            quantity = nutrient_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-nutrition-data"]/div[contains(@class, "field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-recipe-nutrition")]/div/span/text()').extract()
        except:
            continue

        nutrient = Nutrients()
        nutrient['name'] =  name
        nutrient['quantity'] = quantity
        nutrients.append(nutrient)
    nutrient_name = []
    x = nutrients[0].get('name')
    for i in x:
        if i != "\n":
            nutrient_name.append(i)
    nutrients[0]['name'] = nutrient_name

    recipe['nutrients'] = nutrients

    # Recipe time
    duration_nodes = sel.xpath('//div[@class = "panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-recipe-time recipe-time"]/div[@class = "pane-content"]/div[@class = "field-collection-container clearfix"]')

    for duration_node in duration_nodes:
        try:
            path = duration_node.xpath('//div[@class = "panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-recipe-time recipe-time"]/div[@class = "pane-content"]/div/div[@class = "field-recipe-time"]/div/div/span[1]/text()').extract()
            if path == 'Prep: ':
                recipe['prep_time'] = duration_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-recipe-time"]/div/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
            elif path == 'Cook: ':
                recipe['cook_time'] = duration_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-recipe-time"]/div/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
            elif path == 'Total: ':
                recipe['total_time'] = duration_node.xpath('//div[@class = "field-recipe-time"]/div/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
        except:
            continue


    # Number of Servings
    recipe['servings'] = sel.xpath("substring-after(//div[@class = 'panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-yield']/div[@class = 'pane-content']/div[@itemprop = 'yield']/div[@class = 'field-yield']/text(), ': ')").extract()

    return recipe
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-recipe-time recipe-time">
    <h2 class="pane-title">Recipe Time</h2>

  <div class="pane-content">
        <div class="field-collection-container clearfix">
      <div class="field-recipe-time">
        <div class="field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-recipe-time">
        <div class="recipe-time-info">
          <span class="recipe-time-text">Prep: </span>
          <span class="recipe-time-duration">25 Minutes</span>
        </div>
        </div>  </div>
          <div class="field-recipe-time">
            <div class="field-collection-view clearfix view-mode-recipe-time field-collection-view-final">
        <div class="recipe-time-info">
          <span class="recipe-time-text">Cook: </span>
          <span class="recipe-time-duration">45 Minutes</span>
        </div>
        </div>  </div>
        </div>  </div>


          </div>
```

Comment: `path` is a list, and you are comparing it against a string, `.extract()` returns a list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with your xpath construction. More often when there are lots of html elements the chances of missing any element increases. If you find it difficult to construct the relative xpath, I would suggest you to use your browser's xpath selector. You can right click on the element and select the relative xpath. Try this:

```
    duration_nodes = sel.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div')
    for duration_node in duration_nodes:
        try:
            path = ''.join(duration_node.xpath('div/div/span[1]/text()').extract())
            if path == 'Prep: ':
                recipe['prep_time'] = duration_node.xpath('div/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
            elif path == 'Cook: ':
                recipe['cook_time'] = duration_node.xpath('div/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
            elif path == 'Total: ':
                 recipe['total_time'] = duration_node.xpath('div/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
        except:
            continue
```